# place jquery mobile checkbox on collapsible header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, collapsable

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me. I am trying place a collapsible block with jQuery mobile 1.2

Now I have the problem that I want to have an checkbox inside a collapsible header and i placed but when I click on the checkbox the click event is not fired but instead the block gets uncollapsed or collapsed. Checkbox tick and untick is also not fired.

What i want is, when I click on checkbox only untick and tick should work and collapsible event should not work and when I click on the plus icon or outside the checkbox only collapsible even should work not checkbox event.

problem happening on Google Chrome and firefox.

```
  [http://jsfiddle.net/Ae5CU/5/][1]
```

issue 2)

checkbox style should look same as the current without label, is it possible?

```
  [http://jsfiddle.net/Ae5CU/6/][2]
```

Comment: I dont understand your second question, what do you mean by "checkbox style should look same as the current without label, is it possible?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Here is the link to solve the issue.

```
{http://jsfiddle.net/sunwebsite/493e5/1/}
```